# Disable action in form when using AJAX commands?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When one uses AJAX commands with Jquery, is it necessary to disable form action parameter in the HTML? The load URL and the action point to the same place, so is it necessary to have the action parameter?

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  It seems pretty clear and succinct to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `event` object's `preventDefault()` method, which will disable any default behavior associated with the element type.  This is very important for links and form submit buttons.

For example:

```
<!-- you have this link -->
<a id="clickme" href="test.html">Click me</a>
```

You can disable the loading of `test.html` by using `preventDefault()`

```
$('#clickme').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // ...
});
```

You can also `return false` in your click function for the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I think is useful only for clarity of code. When you put your code to make the AJAX call you can get the url from the form's action but that depends on you.

Try to be clear and consistent it's my advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting the form via Ajax, then you just need to make sure there is not a way for the form to be submitted traditionally. You can either remove the `form` tags themselves, remove the actions, or remove any `submit` buttons. You can also capture the `submit` event of the form and just `return false` to prevent the form from doing a postback submit.